# updating records in table A from table B if column XYZ ( checksum ) changes in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, rdbms, greenplum

I am having a table A and table B.

Table A is created from Table B ( and few other table join operation ).
Table A has all of its column which are subset of column in table B.

There is a column called as check_sum in table A and table B. This is basically a calculated column and if any column value changes then check_sum ( calculated value ) changes as well. 
For example:

```
Table A ( schema ):
cust_id ( pk ), cust_name, cust_location, check_sum ... other columns ( no need to worry about them )

Table B ( schema ) :
cust_id ( pk ), cust_name, cust_location, check_sum
```

Initially table B and A have entries like below:

```
Table A:  ( sample record )
1, John, USA, abc222abc, ... other columns

Table B:  ( sample record )
1, John, USA, abc222abc
```

Now lets say John changes his country location to UK, then corresponding entry in TABLE A looks like this

```
Table A:  ( sample record )
1, John, UK, checkSumChanged, ... other columns
```

Now i need to update my table B accordingly, so that instead of location of John as USA it should have it as UK. 
Column checksum is helpful here, since its value changes in Table A if any column changes.

This is the part i am stuck at. Not able to update just "CHANGED" rows from Table A to Table B. I have following query below. It is updating all rows instead of just the changed rows.

Here is the query.

```
UPDATE tableB 
SET 
    tableB.cust_name = tableA.cust_name, 
    tableB.cust_location = tableA.cust_location,
    tableB.check_sum = tableA.check_sum
FROM 
    tableA inner join tableB 
    on tableA.cust_id = tableB.cust_id
    and tableA.check_sum != tableB.check_sum
```

Any ideas or suggestion how can i correct my query to just update the changed record.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Which database you are using `mysql,postgresql` ?

Comment: postgresql but once i understand the logic i can make it work with any database.

Comment: Try this with a `where` clause
    `tableA inner join tableB 
    on tableA.cust_id = tableB.cust_id
    WHERE tableA.check_sum != tableB.check_sum`

Answer (score 2):

Do it without a join:

```
update B
SET cust_name = a.cust_name, checksum = a.checksum, cust_location = a.cust_location
FROM a
WHERE a.custid = b.custid AND a.checksum != b.checksum;
```